# How to add condition in while true

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here i just put some code to **scrape** some data from website and i want to take these data from all page so i make a loop while true: and there have 550 page but i want to **scrape** only 10 or 20 page so how i put condition to pull 10/20 or 100 page

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

re=requests.get("https://katmoviehd.sk/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(re.text,"html.parser")


while True:
       
    page = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]
    
    Category = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'meta-category')
    Category
    
    Category_list = []
    
    for i in Category:
        Category2 = i.text
        Category_list.append(Category2)
    
    link_list = []
    
    for i in page:
        link = (i.find("a")['href'])
        link_list.append(link)
        
        
        
    title_list = []    
    
    for i in page:
        title = (i.find("a")['title'])
        title_list.append(title)
        
        
    Table = pd.DataFrame({'Links':link_list, 'Title':title_list, 'Category':Category_list})
   
    next_page = soup.find('a', class_ = 'next page-numbers').get('href')
    next_page
    
    url = next_page
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if and use break:

```
while True:
    ....

    if time_to_quit:
          break
```

Or use a variable instead of true:

```
keep_going = True

whlle keep_going:
    ...
    keep_going = not am_i_done() # or whatever fits
```

Or a page count:

```
pages = 0
while pages < 20:
    ...
    pages += 1
```

Comment: i am noob so please tell me where to code this line in the end of my code..?

Comment: ... is your code inside while loop, so you should be able to compare my sturcture to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have a simple *counter* variable outside your loop, and every time you successfully read a page, update the *counter* by 1.
Then instead of while loop with True condition, you can do something like this:

```
counter = 0
TOTAL_PAGES = 20 # or 100 whatever you  decide
...

while counter < TOTAL_PAGES: 
  ...
  counter += 1
```

Comment: where i put this code..? in the end on my code

Comment: yes. define the variable before the loop condition, and then increment the counter after moving to the next page

Comment: check the code https://imgur.com/a/v9fgnuC it stuck

Comment: @ShovoMurad so replace 'while True' condition, with the one I mentioned 'while counter < TOTAL_PAGES' and then have the counter += 1 as the next line after it